# Friend Requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-requests, facebook-friends

In the following example: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ how can I fill the friend lists drop down with the users custom lists?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to prompt the user for the extended "read_friendlists" permission, pull the friendlists data from the user when they authorize your application, then use the same lists to build the custom filters parameter:

"Additionally, an application can suggest custom filters as dictionaries with a name key and a user_ids key, which respectively have values that are a string and a list of user IDs. name is the name of the custom filter that will show in the selector. user_ids is the list of friends to include, in the order they are to appear."